# Creating multiple rows in databases

Tags: database, python-3.x

I'm not sure why I can't test my function. My desired output is ID, then Room, but if there are multiple rooms for the same ID, then put it in a new row, like

```
  ID   Room
  1   SW128 SW 143
  into 
  ID Room
   1  SW128
   1  SW143
```

This is some of the data in the file.

```
   1,SW128,SW143
   2,SW309
   3,AA205
   4,AA112,SY110
   5,AC223
   6,AA112,AA206
```

but I can't even test my function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def create_location_table(db, loc_file):
'''Location table has format ID, Room'''

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con. cursor()
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Locations''')
# create the table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Locations (id TEXT, Room TEXT)''')



# Add the rows
loc_file = open('locations.csv', 'r')
loc_file.readline()
for line in loc_file:
    d = {}
    data = line.split(',')
    ID = data[0]
    Room = data[1:]
    for (ID, Room) in d.items():
        if Room not in d:
            d[ID] = [Room]
            for i in Rooms:
                cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO Locations VALUES(?, ?)''', (ID, 
                 Room))
     # commit and close cursor and connection
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `d` is always an empty dict, so the `for (ID, Room) in d.items()` won't do anything. What you need to do is looping over `Room`. And you don't need the `d` dict.

```
def create_location_table(db, loc_file):
    '''Location table has format ID, Room'''

    con = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con. cursor()
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Locations''')
    # create the table
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Locations (id TEXT, Room TEXT)''')

    # open the CSV
    csv_content = open(loc_file, 'r')

    for line in csv_content:
        data = line.strip().split(',')
        # made lowercase following PEP8, but 'id' is a built in name in python
        idx = data[0]
        rooms = data[1:]
        # loop through the rooms of this line and insert one row per room
        for room in rooms:
            cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO Locations VALUES(?, ?)''', (idx, room))
            # for debug purposes only
            print('INSERT INTO Locations VALUES(%s, %s)' % (idx, room))
    # commit and close cursor and connection
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()

# call the method
create_location_table('db.sqlite3', 'locations.csv')
```

Note: Following [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) I made your variables lowercase.

EDIT: post full code example, use `loc_file` parameter

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160137/discussion-on-answer-by-masterfloda-creating-multiple-rows-in-databases).